# What, if anything, can be said about $\log(f(g(x))$

Tags: logarithms

Given that you can restrict $f$ and $g$ to any form (convex, monotonic, etc.) what can be said about $\log(f(g(x)))$ (if anything)?

For context:

I am looking to consider replacing weight updates in neural network backpropagation with $\log$ weight updates as a way to deal with vanishing gradients in long chains of partial derivatives. The form for a neural network looks like:

$g(W_2g(W_1x)) = \hat{y}$

With $g$ and $f$ as any arbitrary non-linear functions. During backpropagation you compute $\Delta W_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial W_i}$ which ends up looking like a large chain of partial derivatives $\Delta W_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial W_i}$. Taking $\log{\Delta W_i}$ allows you to add those partial derivatives together instead of multiplying, but you are left with $\log{\Delta W_i}$ instead of $\Delta W_i$.

I think the question ultimate is about if it is possible to constrain the forward model in such a way (perhaps limiting it's expressiveness) that we might use $\log{\Delta W_i}$ to update weights without needing to take $e^{\log{\Delta W_i}}$. One of my first thoughts was to take $\log{\hat{y}}$ and sort of see what happens, but I realized I didn't know much about what I might be able to do with $\log(f(g(x))$.

I'm thinking there might be concepts like Jensen's Inequality but for composite functions and then we seek to minimize our loss function $L$ as a upper or lower bound.

Comment: $f(g(x))$ can be anything and you'd better write it as $h(x)$. Then $\log(h(x))$ is anything. Now the dependencies on $W_i$ make that a different question. But where is $f$ gone ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a specialist but I have seen such forms in the following book : 
Tarantola - Elements for Physics
Free access here: [www.ipgp.fr/~tarantola/Files/Professional/Books/](http://www.ipgp.fr/~tarantola/Files/Professional/Books/)

More generally that seems to be linked to Lie group algebra and how to describe quantities in such spaces, with the perk that you mention (addition of consecutive transformations). Tarantola applies such ideas to propose a new way of formulating physical problems (revolutionary in my eyes, we really ought to pay more attention to this). It changed my views on what logarithms may conceal.

As for the link to NN, I think you will have to work on it yourself, as Tarantola unfortunately passed away a few years ago...